# How does CDB mastering work in Tomasulo's algorithm?

Tags: computer-architecture

I understand that implementations of Tomasulo's algorithm feature a common data bus (CDB) that each functional unit writes its output to. Each reservation station can listen on the CDB for its operands.

I'm curious how practical implementations deal with multiple functional units wanting to drive the CDB concurrently. Does the CDB multiplex between the functional units? How would the mux decide which functional unit to select each clock cycle (is it round robin, some sort of priority selection based on position in the ROB, etc.)? If the CDB does multiplex, doesn't this create a bottleneck that limits the issue rate of the processor?

The only other solution I can think of is one bus per unit, but this defeats the purpose of the "common" data bus and seems like it would be a nightmare to route to each reservation station.

The only literature I've been able to find about this is [the last slide of this presentation](https://www.eecs.harvard.edu/%7Edbrooks/cs246/cs246-lecture-speculation.pdf) which seems to allude to the problems I mentioned above.

Comment: I think this is a great topic, but I also think you will find few people with specific experience. If I were you, I'd find a few key people at universities and ask them to either help or to refer you to someone who may be interested in helping. (I have glancing experience because I worked at Intel on chipset testing. I don't know enough to write a proper answer here.) If you want help and if my assumption is correct about the difficulty in finding those with specific experience is right then you may need to provide a serious expansion and narrowing of your question to bring others up to date.

Comment: There's no bottleneck, because each instruction that's issued generates a single result that will need to pass over the CDB at some point in the future. So as long as the CDB handles results at the same rate that instructions are issued, there's no problem. A simple priority encoder suffices for gating results onto the CDB. I did some design and high-level simulation work on such a processor about 40 years ago, and I still think it was one of the more interesting things I've done, especially for a kid just out of college.

Comment: Well I'm no expert but I think there would be some kind of (priority) arbitrator like in real buses like classic PCI. Probably the station *just know* when it's their time to put the result in (the reservation station drives the process)